# Which are some formal approaches for predicting multiple binary time series?

Tags: time-series, binary-data, supervised-learning, boosting, time-varying-covariate

I have **10000 roughly similar individuals**. For each individual I've got a response **(binary time series)**, 200 explanatory features (also time series), and 10 static features that represent characteristics of the individuals. I want to **predict the one-step ahead** value of the response for all of the 10000 individuals.

**Training data** looks like this:

| individual | time | response | ts_feature_1 | ... | static_feature_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 00:00:00 | 0 | 0.1 | ... | A |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 00:01:00 | 1 | 0.4 | ... | A |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 00:00:00 | 1 | -0.1 | ... | B |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10000 | 31/12/2020 23:00:00 | 0 | 0.1 | ... | C |

If I had 1 individual, I would **cast the data as a supervised learning problem** (classification) and apply machine learning algorithms.

But I have 10000 individuals and I don't want to have 10000 different models. Instead I want 1 model that can model the 10000 individuals at the same time.

I'm currently combining the 10000 datasets into an unique dataset and training a xgboost on this unique dataset but I couldn't find bibliography that formalizes this approach.

Can you recommend a **formal approach** to solve this problem?

If possible, please cite sources.